# Does NativeScript Sidekick remove comments in XML and JavaScript and minify the source codes while building the app?

Tags: javascript, xml, webpack, nativescript, uglifyjs

I use NativeScript Sidekick.
When I build my app, I turn on Webpack and uglifyjs, but do these options remove all my comments in my XML and JS files? Do they also minify XML and JS files?

I feel minify XML and JS files and removal of all comments in both XML and JS, improves speed and privacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SideKick has nothing to do with this, it's just a GUI tool for everything you could possibly do with {N} CLI.

If you are using Webpack (`--bundle`) for your build, then it's all about Webpack & UglifyJs (the default minimizer) configuration. I think the default configuration removes comments and the XML is embedded as a string within JS file.

Comment: So, the answer is yes or no?
If I enable webpack, comments are removed in both XML and JS? and the code are minified?

Comment: The answer is Yes, it removes comments if you have enabled Webpack. XML also minified in a way as mentioned above.